# How to add validation in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add validations like range, compare, a maximum and minimum value

I have tried but this is not doing what I want

Here is my code: CONTROLLER

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPass(userPass model, string phoneNumber, String password, String repassword)
    {

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.repassword)&&!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.password))
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var db = new MongoContext())
                {
                    db._database.GetCollection<userPass>("userPass");

                    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_phoneNumber", phoneNumber);

                    var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
                        .Set("password", password);

                    db._database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("farmers").UpdateOne(filter, update, null);

                    return RedirectToAction("Login", new {Message = "password has been reset"});
                }

            }
        }

        return View(model);

    }
```

VIEW:

```
                @Html.ValidationMessage("userPass", "")     
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" required="" name="repassword" align="center">    
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Update</button>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace CroplyticsWeb.ViewModels.MongoDbModels
{
    public class userPass
    {
        [BsonElement("password")] 
        [Range(10000000,99999999)]
        [Required]
        public String password { get; set; }


        [BsonElement("repassword")]
        [Range(10000000,99999999)]
        [Compare("password", ErrorMessage = " ")]
        public String repassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is not doing anything.

Comment: What would a range of 10000000 to 99999999 mean to a `string`?

Comment: Means the length of string should be 8 digits

Comment: That's what [StringLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) is for (not `Range`)

Comment: find link to understand and code https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/13048b/model-validation-in-Asp-Net-mvc909/

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Range on Strings. Instead use String Length

```
public class userPass
{


    [Required]
    [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Password cannot exceed 40 characters")] 
    public String password { get; set; }


   [Required]
   [StringLength(40,  MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Username must be atleast 5 characters")] 
    public String userName{ get; set; }
}
```

You can read more about [StringLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) Here and Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604576/asp-net-data-annotations-field-length)